# Problemas con punteros y violación de segmento

Tags: c, codeblocks, fgets

Estoy teniendo problemas con un proyecto que consiste en simular un *minishell*. El usuario teclea un comando y el programa de momento separa con `strtok()` la línea introducida y mira a ver si es un comando interno como `cd, export`, `jobs` y `source`, y de momento da una explicación de lo que hace ese comando, que aún no he acabado de completar.

Cuando lo ejecuto en *CodeBlocks* el programa funciona perfectamente, pero al compilarlo y ejectutarlo por consola de Linux me de violación de segmento.

Al parecer, al compilar, reporta avisos en una serie de líneas detalladas más abajo. Estos avisos tienen que ver con el manejo de punteros y he estado leyendo en foros y tutoriales pero no doy con la solución.

Nota: Los errores y los warnings están comentados en el código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PROMPT "$"

int parse_args(char **args, char *line){
    char *token;
    int n=0;

    //Aquí da warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
    token=strtok(line," "); 

    while(token!=NULL){
        printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
        *args=token;
        n++;
        *args++;

        //Aquí da warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
        token=strtok(NULL," ");
    }
    printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
    *args=token;
    return n;
}

//Aquí me dice que espera un char* pero que recibe un char**
char *read_line(char *line){ 
    printf("%s ",PROMPT);

        //Aquí da warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
        *line = malloc(sizeof(500));
    fgets(line,500,stdin);
    return line;
}

//Aquí me dice que espera un char* pero que recibe un char**
int execute_line(char *line){
    char**args;
    parse_args(args,line);
    check_internal(args);
    return 0;
}

int check_internal(char **args){
    if( strcmp(*args, "cd")==0 ){
        internal_cd();
    } else{
        if( strcmp(*args, "export")==0 ){
            internal_export();
        }else{
            if( strcmp(*args, "source")==0 ){
                internal_source();
            }else{
                if( strcmp(*args, "jobs")==0 ){
                    internal_jobs();
                }else{
                    printf("%s","pasa los ifelse\n");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int internal_cd(char **args){
    printf("%s","cambio de directorio\n");
    return 1;
}

int internal_export(char **args) {
    printf("%s","éste es el export\n");
    return 1;
}

int internal_source(char **args) {
    printf("%s","éste es el source\n");
    return 1;
}

int internal_jobs(char **args){
    printf("%s","éste es el jobs\n");
    return 1;
}

void main(){
    char *line;
    while(read_line(&line)){//warning: tipo de puntero incompatible
        execute_line(&line);//warning: tipo de puntero incompatible
    }
}
```

Comment: En tu función main, el llamado a la función read_line deberia ser de la siguiente manera: read_line (line); no debes colocar el &, ya que tu variable line es del tipo char* y eso es exactamente lo que recibe la función. Lo mismo ocurre con tu función execute_line.

Comment: @cventu lo he probado y da segmentation fault. Antes imprimía el PROMPT y dejaba escribir pero con esto que me dices ahora da segmentation fault directamente

Comment: Es que tienes varios problemas a lo largo del código. En tu función read_line aparece lo siguiente: *line = malloc(sizeof(500)).   La forma correcta debería ser: line = malloc(sizeof(500)).   Eso es porque dentro de la función line es un char* y eso es lo que devuelve malloc. Si colocas *line estarás desreferenciando a la variable y estarás intentando asignar un puntero a un entero que es justamente lo que te dice el warning

Comment: Perdón tuve algunos problemas con el formato del texto en los comentarios. La linea debería quedar asi: line = malloc(sizeof(500)); Sin el *

Comment: @cventu vale muchas gracias. Ahora lo miraré y te digo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que funciona sería así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PROMPT "$"

int parse_args(char **args, char *line){
    char *token;
    int n=0;
    token=strtok(line," "); //aquí da warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast (porque faltaba string.h)
    while(token!=NULL){
        printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
        *args=token;
        n++;
        *args++;
        token=strtok(NULL," ");//aquí da warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast (porque faltaba string.h)
    }
    printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
    *args=token;
    return n;
}

char *read_line(char **line){ //aquí me dice que espera un char* pero que recibe un char** - lo correcto es que sea char**
    printf("%s ",PROMPT);
    *line = (char *) malloc(500 * sizeof(char));//aquí da warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast // porque malloc devuelve (void *) y no (char *) - por otra parte sizeof(500) devuelve el tamaño de un int, tú quieres 500 char (500 por el tamaño de un char)
    fgets(*line,500,stdin);
    return *line;
}


int execute_line(char *line){//aquí me dice que espera un char* pero que recibe un char**
    char **args;
    parse_args(args,line);
    check_internal(args);
    return 0;
}

int check_internal(char **args){
    if( strcmp(*args, "cd")==0 ){
        internal_cd();
    } else{
        if( strcmp(*args, "export")==0 ){
            internal_export();
        }else{
            if( strcmp(*args, "source")==0 ){
                internal_source();
            }else{
                if( strcmp(*args, "jobs")==0 ){
                    internal_jobs();
                }else{
                    printf("%s","pasa los ifelse\n");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


int internal_cd(char **args){
    printf("%s","cambio de directorio\n");
    return 1;
}

int internal_export(char **args) {
    printf("%s","éste es el export\n");
    return 1;
}

int internal_source(char **args) {
    printf("%s","éste es el source\n");
    return 1;
}

int internal_jobs(char **args){
    printf("%s","éste es el jobs\n");
    return 1;
}

void main(){
   char *line;
    while(read_line(&line)){//warning: tipo de puntero incompatible - ahora read_line recive char **
        execute_line(line);//warning: tipo de puntero incompatible - aquí no necesitas el prefijo porque line ya es una dirección como la espera excecute_line
    }
    free(line);
}
```

En este otro ejemplo, definiendo un nuevo tipo, las cosas quedan mucho más claras:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PROMPT "$"

typedef char* string;

int parse_args(string *args, string line){
    string token;
    int n=0;
    token=strtok(line," "); //aquí da warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
    while(token!=NULL){
        printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
        *args=token;
        n++;
        *args++;
        token=strtok(NULL," ");//aquí da warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
    }
    printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
    *args=token;
    return n;
}

string read_line(string *line){ //aquí me dice que espera un char* pero que recibe un char**
    printf("%s ",PROMPT);
    *line = malloc(500 * sizeof(char));//aquí da warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
    fgets(*line,500,stdin);
    return *line;
}


int execute_line(string line){//aquí me dice que espera un char* pero que recibe un char**
    string *args;
    parse_args(args,line);
    check_internal(args);
    return 0;
}

int check_internal(string *args){
    if( strcmp(*args, "cd")==0 ){
        internal_cd();
    } else{
        if( strcmp(*args, "export")==0 ){
            internal_export();
        }else{
            if( strcmp(*args, "source")==0 ){
                internal_source();
            }else{
                if( strcmp(*args, "jobs")==0 ){
                    internal_jobs();
                }else{
                    printf("%s","pasa los ifelse\n");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


int internal_cd(string *args){
    printf("%s","cambio de directorio\n");
    return 1;
}

int internal_export(string *args) {
    printf("%s","éste es el export\n");
    return 1;
}

int internal_source(string *args) {
    printf("%s","éste es el source\n");
    return 1;
}

int internal_jobs(string *args){
    printf("%s","éste es el jobs\n");
    return 1;
}

void main(){
   string line;
    while(read_line(&line)){//warning: tipo de puntero incompatible
        execute_line(line);//warning: tipo de puntero incompatible
    }
}
```

Porque en la función `read_line`, tú necesitas modificar el contenido de `line` sin embargo no está permitido porque `line` pertenece a `main` entonces lo haces a través de su dirección. En `read_line` modificas el contenido donde apunta `line`. El mismo criterio debes aplicarlo a `parse_args`. Es un caso análogo al ejemplo de intercambio de enteros del libro de K&R. La función `fgets` no tiene límite, lee hasta encontrar un `EOF` o un `\n` pero sólo guarda los primeros n carácteres. Los máximos dependerán del sistema donde lo corras. Lo último que te sucede es normal porque `fgets` incluye el `\n` que el usuario ingresó en `stdin`. Para solucionarlo debes reemplazar el último carácter por `\0`. Por último no olvides liberar la memoria cuando ya no la uses.

Entonces el programa completo queda así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PROMPT "$"

typedef char* string;
typedef  string* list;

int parse_args(list *args, string line){
    string token;
    int n=0;
    *args = malloc(500 * sizeof(string)); // máximo 500 elementos
    token=strtok(line," ");
    while(token!=NULL){
        printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
        *(*args+n)=token;
        n++;
        token=strtok(NULL," ");
    }
    printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
    *(*args+n)=token;
    free(token); // liberar, no se usa más
    return n;
}

string read_line(string *line){
    printf("%s ",PROMPT);
    *line = malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
    fgets(*line,500,stdin);
    *(*line + strlen(*line) - 1) = '\0'; // quitar el '\n' final
    return *line;
}


int execute_line(string line){
    list args;
    parse_args(&args,line);
    check_internal(args);
    free(args); // liberar, no se usa más
    return 0;
}

int check_internal(list args){
    if( strcmp(*args, "cd")==0 ){
        internal_cd(args);
    } else{
        if( strcmp(*args, "export")==0 ){
            internal_export(args);
        }else{
            if( strcmp(*args, "source")==0 ){
                internal_source(args);
            }else{
                if( strcmp(*args, "jobs")==0 ){
                    internal_jobs(args);
                }else{
                    printf("%s","pasa los ifelse\n");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


int internal_cd(list args){
    printf("%s","cambio de directorio\n");
    return 1;
}

int internal_export(list args) {
    printf("%s","éste es el export\n");
    return 1;
}

int internal_source(list args) {
    printf("%s","éste es el source\n");
    return 1;
}

int internal_jobs(list args){
    printf("%s","éste es el jobs\n");
    return 1;
}

void main(){
   string line;
    while(read_line(&line)){
        execute_line(line);
        free(line); // liberar, no se usa más
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Ahora funciona, pero tengo una serie de dudas que agradecería que me solventaras: la primera es por qué tiene que recibir un char** la función read_line? la segunda es si hay alguna variable definida como máximo de línea o algo similar para no depender de un valor exacto al hacer malloc y la última duda es que al ejecutar, y esto ya me pasaba ejecutándolo en codeblocks, hace un salto de línea entre el último token y el token null, a qué puede ser que se deba, al while?? Gracias

Comment: Edité la respuesta contestando tus preguntas

Answer (score 0):

Te faltan las pre-declaraciones de todas las funciones que utilizas, además de la inclusión de string.h.

Haz las pre-declaraciones, coloca el

```
#include <string.h>
```

y te dará un montón de errores (no avisos).

Cambia el código y verás.